# Qt- iOS memory issue when add more images

Tags: ios, qt, memory, qml

HI I am developing an application using qt/qml.
I am able to load all the images in windows and iOS device as well when add all images are added in to the `qrc:` file.

```
qrc:///graphics/feature/image1.png
```

I have lot of images, when image are adding more qt got error  `memory issue`

So, I tried to load images dynamically (with out adding images to `qrc:` file) by using

```
file:graphics/feature/image1.png
```

In windows it is working fine. But, in iOS images are not loading.

How do I use large number of images with qt/qml

Comment: Are the images present in the iOS application bundle?

Comment: yes, I have added to the bundle

Comment: Also run the application from the QTCrater itself.

Comment: Then obviously when your iOS application runs, its current working directory isn't in the folder you think it is. You must explicitly set it.

Comment: I the window itself I am getting the memory issue.

Comment: In the windows  itself I am getting the memory issue.

Comment: How much images do you load and what is the total size of them?

Comment: aboce 200 MB images.Since, application have 50+ features.